# How to set image and text side by side

Tags: html, css

i want to set my lion image and h1 tag tex side by side. but something is messing up. dont know what is it.

```css
h2 { 
 width:50%;         
 float:right;
 padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin:0 auto;
  }
.lion {
width:10%;
 float: left;
 padding-right:30%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<img src="texlion-w.png" class="lion">
<h2> നമസ്കാരം, എന്റെ പേര് അഭിജിത്ത് കെ എ.വരക്കാനും, എഴുതാനും ഇഷ്ടമാണ്.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "messing up"

Comment: Use code snippet (`CTRL+M`) to show a code that reproduces the problem easily.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `display` element. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Comment: @j08691 I mean that the image and text is not placing correctly side by side.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález oh okey.

Comment: @KenSharp is that `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

Use FlexBox:

```css
.flex{
    display: flex;
}

.flex h2{
    width:50%;          
    padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" class="lion">
    <h2> നമസ്കാരം, എന്റെ പേര് അഭിജിത്ത് കെ എ.വരക്കാനും, എഴുതാനും ഇഷ്ടമാണ്.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<div id="continer">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdti_7DIIq6sh7Y24zXvfeBEab5st3M_-bEitNykuSGnXUXRXu" class="lion">
<h2> നമസ്കാരം, എന്റെ പേര് അഭിജിത്ത് കെ എ.വരക്കാനും, എഴുതാനും ഇഷ്ടമാണ്.</h2>
</div>


<style>
#continer{
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
}
h2 {    
width: 50%;
float: left;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.lion {
width: 30%;
float: left;
padding-right: 5%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
</style>
```